# Conditionally styling an array value from an API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am grabbing data from an API that is very easy to utilize, the values for percent change can either be positive or negative. I am trying to add a class to the item so if the value is negative I can display a class and vice versa.

Here is what I've tried so far with no luck:

```
<li v-for="info in infos.slice(0, 5)">  -- Grabs first 5 items in API
    <div :class="{ positive: info.percent_change > 0 }" v-html="info.percent_change"></div>
</li>
```

The code properly displays the percent_change value but does not apply any class to it regardless if it is negative or positive.

Sample output showing no class names:

```
<li><div class="">0.8%</div></li>
<li><div class="">-6.57%</div></li>
```

Comment: why `name.percent_change` and not `info.percent_change`?

Comment: you're making a typo you should set `info.percent_change`

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem, I changed some of the wording for the question. Yes, it should be info.percent_change, but this still doesn't make the class work.

Comment: could you provide more code?

Comment: I added more code + a sample output. Thanks for looking into this, I really need a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear `%` sign using `replace('%','')` as follows :

```
<div :class="{ positive: getNumValue(info.percent_change) > 0 }" v-html="info.percent_change"></div> </li>
```

and the method looks like :

```
methods:{
    getNumValue(percent){
       return percent!=undefined?percent.replace('%',''):0;
    }
   ...
 }
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense and I believe this is the solution, but I get this console error:  Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" and nothing displays. Perhaps I need to create a method for this?

Comment: Yes, this worked perfect! Thank-you so much for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Better parse the value first because it's comparing string against 0 (zero).

Something like `{ positive: parseFloat(info.percent_change) > 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string value and convert it to float value which can be compared with 0.

### html

```
<div :class="{ positive: isPositive(info.percent_change) }" 
      v-html="info.percent_change"></div> </li>
```

### ts

```
public isPositive(v:string){
   return parseFloat(v) > 0; //parseFloat will ignore the %
}
```